# Protect mutliple pages in a template folder

Tags: users, login

I made a member area with multiple pages in a `member-area` template folder.
I d like to protecte all pages in this folder.

I know the `isLoggedIn` function to protect a page in a twig template.
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.session

```
{% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %}
    <a href="{{ logoutUrl }}">Logout</a>
{% endif %}
```

But what would be the best way to protect multiple pages ?

Put the control on `_layouts/base` or `_layouts/site` templates?
Note: And above that problem I got an ajax login form (I can make a dedicated login page if it is more simple and no choice)

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much nailed it.

If you have multiple pages that require an authenticated session, then have all of those pages extend a template that uses something like [{% requireLogin %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/requirelogin).

Comment: Sorry I am lost here : I did a `require-login` template which extends `_layouts/site`. Then in this template I have a condition `{% if not craft.session.isLoggedIn %}` in `block main` for example. But it does not work. I should stop extending the parent template when the user is not logged in no ?

Comment: OK here is what I did : put a flag in the pages that need privacy '{% set requireLogin = true %}' and in `_layouts/site` (extended by all pages) I added the control `{% if (requireLogin is defined and not craft.session.isLoggedIn) %}` display the login box `else` display regular `block main`. Looks good no?